# html <object> not working on chrome. [+ knockout]

Tags: javascript, html, knockout-2.0

I'm using  to fallback to default image if there is no concrete image for current item. This is working properly for firefox and even for IE8+ but chrome always display default image.

```
<object style="display: inline-block; width: 226px; height: 340px;" data-bind="attr: { data: ImageUrl }">
    <img style="display: inline-block; width: 226px; height: 340px;" src="~/Content/images/default.png" />
</object>
```

to be honest I don't know even where to start searching for issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to specify the type attribute, wich seems to be mandatory to chrome.

```
<object style="display: inline-block; width: 226px; height: 340px;" data-bind="attr: { data: ImageUrl }" type="image/png">
    <img style="display: inline-block; width: 226px; height: 340px;" src="~/Content/images/default.png" />
</object>
```

Try this fiddle that illustrates the solution to your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/SEYwf/